# Preventing redirect loop with .htaccess parameter re-write

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Let me start by saying I am not an .htaccess or Apache expert by any means. But I have the need to append a hashed term to the end of a URL query.

For example:

> http://www.example.com/?query_string=stuff

becomes

> http://www.example.com/?query_string=stuff#otherstuff

I am using the following rule (entire .htaccess file):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ppw_confirm=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/?ppw_confirm=%1#go [NE,L]
```

**THE PROBLEM**

After adding #go to the end of the parameter string, the .htaccess file still reads the ?ppw_confirm= query. It then attempts to perform a second redirect after which an infinite loop ensues.

I've been searching around for hours with no luck. Basically, I need a way to prevent .htaccess from re-writing twice to thus prevent this endless loop.

Open to any and all suggestions :)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to send an HTTP `30x` response to the client to add the `#go`?

Comment: Boy, I wish I knew what that meant :) Basically, I am redirecting an incoming query parameter and then adding the `code`#go. Just stuck in the endless loop issue.

Comment: Is the client browser getting the `#go` added to its address bar?

Comment: Ah, yes, the `#go` is being added to the URL bar at the end of the entire parameter, which looks something like this:

`http://www.example.com/?ppw_confirm=1&token=EC-1MV99112AX383650S&PayerID=PQN8BZYCRGYUY#go`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#go` part isn't something you can work with in rewrite rules at all; it's client-side, not sent to the server when making a request for that resource, so you're not able to make decisions in rules based on it.

Maybe as part of the redirect, add an additional variable to the query string, then look for that variable and prevent the redirect when it's present?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ppw_confirm=(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !r=1
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/?ppw_confirm=%1&r=1#go [NE,L]
```